# How to replace the washing machine IDOS pump?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a bosch washing machine series 8 with IDOS system for 3 years. The IDOS pump for fabric softener is working properly, but the detergent pump is out of order. How should I replace that pump?
[image]
What I have done:
I removed the detergent drawer and after washing, I removed the upper compartment and found two pumps that have four crv 2.5 screws (five-bladed screw).

[image]

I removed the screws, but only got access to two gears. The pump motor is located inside the upper chamber and the cover of the upper chamber must be opened, but it seems as if the cap is completely pressed and stuck to the chamber. It does not have any screws.
[image]
My problem was mentioned by someone else a few years ago in [another forum](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/bosch-i-dos-washing-machine-drawer-disassembly.537779/), but no proper answer was given to it.

The price of the drawer is 160 euros [on Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Waschmitteldosiereinrichtung-Dosiereinrichtung-Waschmitteleinsp%C3%BClschale-Einsp%C3%BClschale-Waschmaschine/dp/B07CYVTWY1), but shipping it would be expensive for me and almost impossible. So if I can just change the pump motor, it will be great.

Comment: Have you got the manual? Some sites have them on line...

Comment: @SolarMike, This is a specialized job, and there is nothing written in the manual about how to replace the IDOS pump. It is only explained in relation to how to clean it.

Comment: So, did you inspect the cover? held down by clips? think internal clips as well, or was it glued? Also could it have been plastic welded ie melted? Any of these would put it outside the skills of most people...

Comment: I think it was glued, or it has been plastic welded. However, I will try to upload more pictures with more details later.

Comment: Hi, I have this exact problem and question, how to get at the motors. Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Found this but no info on getting to the pumps https://www.boards.ie/discussion/2058282608/bosch-i-dos-fixing-the-detergent-drawer

Comment: @iss42, Hi, unfortunately, I still haven't found a solution and I add the detergent manually. The pump for the fabric softener works fine, but I think the pump for the detergent is broken. Someone suggested that I look for stock. Thanks for the link. I tried using contact cleaner spray, but it didn't help. If you find a solution again, I'd be happy to share it with me here.